# Denwer упал (HTTP Error 404)

Tags: apache, denwer, localhost

Доброго всем дня!На локалке в браузере выдёт:

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resourceis not found.

ping до localhost не идет.
но по 80-му порту телнетиться и выдаёт содержание этой бэднутой странички.
В хосте пробовал убирать левые "затыконы" не помогло.Антивирусник пробовал отрубать (брандмауэр от него не стоит), файрволы не юзаю.
Кодить через реальный сервак жутко не удобно.
Подскажте, может кто сталкивался?
И ещё заметил, сам аппаче вырубается, в логе пишет

> :make_sock: could not bind to address
> 127.0.0.1:80   no listening sockets avialable, shotting down

Comment: Ну в первую очередь разберитесь с тем, что у вас нет пинга до локалхост. Так как сервер именно по этому не запускается.

Comment: Пинг - это вообще-то ICMP протокол, входящий в IP, но не являющийся транспортным, как TCP. Для функционирования Веб-сервера он не особенно нужен.  А вот TCP/IP как раз работает, если работает телнет по 80-му порту, и выдаёт страницу! Ошибка Апача, и её исправление хорошо описано здесь: http://habrahabr.ru/post/145189/ . Возможно, что в этом всё и дело! Комменты там тоже почитайте - много полезных замечаний!

Comment: Хотя, очень странно, что телнетом страницу выдаёт, а браузером - нет. Может, в браузере где-то прокси прописался?

Comment: а что значит "Жутко кодить через реальный сервак не удобно."?

Comment: Кодить через реальный сервак жутко не удобно.

Comment: командой netstat  вижу что порт 80 занимает система (PID 4) строка 0.0.0.0:80

Answer (score 1):

У вас просто забит 80 порт. Посмотрите через консоль, но 100% уверен что у вас стоит Skype=)). Измените в настройках скайпа, если не он, посмотрите в консоли что еще весит на 80 порту.

Comment: или поменяйте порт на апаче :). Если не поможет - httpd.conf в студию

Answer (score 0):

1. вообще-то ошибка 404 не обязательно означает что денвер упал
2. проверить занятость порта поможет netstat
3. почему loop ифейс не пингуется разобраться, конечно же, надо

как только вы всё это проанализируете, ответ найдётся сам. Не найдётся - помогу (http://freeprogrammer.ru). Пока для конкретного ответа сведений маловато.